# How to delete hidden ARCore application from Huawei smartphone?

Tags: augmented-reality, arcore

My Huawei P Smart smartphone doesn't support ARCore. Nevertheless, I installed it on this device using [ARCore Patch](https://github.com/thestr4ng3r/arcore-patch), `Terminal` and `adb`. App was installed successfully. But, unfortunately, Huawei still doesn't support ARCore.

**The problem is**: *there's no ARCore app on my smartphone and in Play Store I see the following message*: "**This app isn't compatible with your device anymore.**"

> **Question**: How to delete ARCore app from the phone without resetting Android OS?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For uninstalling ARCore tools I used the following Terminal command:

```
adb uninstall com.google.ar.core
```

If you have the original `apk` installed already, it is necessary to manually uninstall that before, since it is signed with a different key.